Enable public internet traffic to Flask app running in WSL
I have a flask app running in my local laptop with host as 0.0.0.0. When I run this flask app on my windows, I am able to access the endpoints from other laptops/internet. But when I deploy the same flask-app in WSL running in my windows laptop, I am not able to reach to the endpoints from other laptops/internet.
Any suggestions?
I am aware this is not ideal or safe. But I need to enable traffic for few hours to collaborate with a developer working remotely.

I was able to enable the incoming traffic from internet by using ngrok
The installation was pretty easy. They have details for different OS, since I was using ubuntu I installed it using the following
curl -s https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com/ngrok.asc \
| sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ngrok.asc >/dev/null \
&& echo "deb https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com buster main" \
| sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ngrok.list \
&& sudo apt update \
&& sudo apt install ngrok

I launched my flask application on 127.0.0.1:5000
And then in another shell, I started ngrok gateway
ngrok http --domain=add-the-static-domain-you-get-from-ngrok http://127.0.0.1:5000

And finally, my flask app was reachable at:
https://add-the-static-domain-you-get-from-ngrok/apistatus

